# What is does expression<T> do?

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

What does `Expression<T>` do?

I have seen it used in a method similar to:

```
private Expression<Func<MyClass,bool>> GetFilter(...)
{
}
```

Can't you just return the `Func<MyClass,bool>` ?

Google and SO searches have failed me due to the < and > signs.

Comment: Search for `Expression Trees` vs `Anonymous delegates`.

Comment: So Expression<T> is referred to as an Expression Tree?

Comment: It is used to build expression trees.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `TDelegate` represents a delegate type, then `Expression<TDelegate>` represents **a lambda expression that can be converted to a delegate of type `TDelegate` as an expression tree**. This allows you to programatically inspect a lambda expression to extract useful information.

For example, if you have

```
var query = source.Where(x => x.Name == "Alan Turing");
```

then `x => x.Name == "Alan Turning"` can be inspected programatically if it's represented as an expression tree, but not so much if it's thought of as a delegate. This is particularly useful in the case of LINQ providers which will walk the expression tree to convert the lambda expression into a different representation. For example, LINQ to SQL would convert the above expression tree to

```
 SELECT * FROM COMPUTERSCIENTIST WHERE NAME = 'Alan Turing'
```

It can do that because of the representation of the lambda expression as a tree whose nodes can be walked and inspected.

Answer (score 3):

An Expression allows you to inspect the structure of the code inside of the delegate rather than just storing the delegate itself.

As usual, MSDN is pretty clear on the matter:

[MSDN - Expression(TDelegate)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335710.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, this line in the MSDN reference helped:  *an in-memory data representation of the lambda expression*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `Func<>` can be used in place of place of an Expression.  The utility of an expression tree is that it gives remote LINQ providers such as LINQ to SQL the ability to look ahead and see what statements are required to allow the query to function.  In other words, to treate code as data.

```
        //run the debugger and float over multBy2.  It will be able to tell you that it is an method, but it can't tell you what the implementation is.
        Func<int, int> multBy2 = x => 2 * x;
        //float over this and it will tell you what the implmentation is, the parameters, the method body and other data
        System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<int, int>> expression = x => 2 * x;
```

In the code above you can compare what data is available via the debugger.  I invite you to do this.  You will see that Func has very little information available.  Try it again with Expressions and you will see a lot of information including the method body and parameters are visible at runtime.  This is the real power of Expression Trees.